# How to sort Kafka events based on timestamp field in event json

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We receive Kafka events from a source. The json event has a timestamp field. We want to buffer events each 5 mins and sort events based on this timestamp before publishing on new topic. Has anyone done anything similar before?

Comment: Sorting events based upon window of 5 mins is doable using Kafka streams library in Java. Assuming you're proficient with Java, it is doable. Check the Kafka streams [docs](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/overview.html) for further information.